# How to create border in css3

Tags: css, border, css-shapes

[image]

How to create border with help of css3 like the bellow image.

Answer (score 6):

There is a border-radius notation for horizontal and vertical radius,

```
border-radius: horizontal-radius/vertical-radius;
```

Using this you can create the desired border.

```css
.border {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px dashed #aaa;
    border-radius: 50%/20%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">Text Here</div>
```

Modify the border values according to your need.

Comment: Thanks a lot :), this seems to be helpful, but can't we make it dotted as I'm having with the design. I want exactly like that only.

Comment: @amolD Just replace `dashed` with `dotted`.

Comment: @amoID Happy to help you. And the border in your design is not dotted. It's dashed and having a width of 1px. Check this one out: http://jsfiddle.net/wqxqzmar/2/

Comment: Thank you guys, but I am expecting design like I have posted in the image. Is it possible?

Comment: Not matching to my design, anyways thanks for your efforts :)

Comment: I tried, but not getting that dotted line / dash line effect. I want it exactly matching to my design. Otherwise, I need to use an image in background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72128/discussion-between-amold-and-anupam-basak).

Answer (score 0):

You can use border radius in order to get the 'curved' border of the div. Along with adding a dashed border, you can add uppercasing and text aligning for your text.

## Result

[image]

```css
div {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    border: 1px dashed gray; /*Makes dashed border*/
    border-radius: 50%/10px; /*Change the px value in order to change border curvature*/
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: red;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div>Text Here</div>
```